# SORT BY 2 fields if one is not empty other wise sort by other field in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in a table called `saleprice` and `regularprice`. This table houses records for listings for a auction based site. If the user decides they can either put in a `saleprice` that is lower than the `regularprice` OR they can simple put in a `regularprice` and leave the `saleprice` empty.

I have built a `select` that allows the user to view the records from Low to High OR High to Low based on the price. Problem is if there is a `regularprice` then the `saleprice` field will be empty. If there is a `saleprice` then both the `regularprice` and `saleprice` fields will contain a value and of course the `saleprice` will be lower.

I am trying to return the records based on what the user selects but I cant get my statement to return the records properly searching both columns.

Basically I need to sort by if `saleprice` is not empty then use `regularprice` else just use `regularprice`

Here are my examples I have come up so far

**Low to High**

```
SELECT * FROM market_posts
WHERE live = 1 AND category = '1'
ORDER BY IF(saleprice != '',saleprice,regularprice) ASC
```

**High To Low**

```
SELECT * FROM market_posts
WHERE live = 1 AND category = '1'
ORDER BY IF(saleprice != '',saleprice,regularprice) DESC
```

Comment: `IF(saleprice IS NOT NULL, saleprice, regularprice)` ?

Comment: This could be done a few different ways depending on "What the user selects" Can you be more clear on what the user is selecting or those options. Other wise the answers you'll get here will be a best guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `saleprice` is `NULL` when it is not set, then use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT *
FROM market_posts
WHERE live = 1 AND category = '1'
ORDER BY COALESCE(saleprice, regularprice) ASC -- OR DESC
```